# После установки Linux Fedora 36 по соседству с Windows 10 перестала запускаться Windows

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot

В принципе, проблему я расписал еще в оглавлении вопроса. При попытке на этапе выбора системы выбрать Windows 10 она пытается загрузиться около 30-ти секунд, затем ноутбук перезагружается и я снова попадаю в меню выбора операционной системы. Хотя до установки линукса винда запускалась за секунд 5, дело точно не в производительности моего ноутбука.